# How can a Quartz.NET job be integrated with dependency injection?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I have a pretty simple command line app and it works fine.  It kicks off jobs correctly:

```
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddQuartz(q => {
    q.ScheduleJob<KasaJob>(trigger => trigger
        .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenSecondDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(2)))
        .WithSimpleSchedule(t => t.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
    );
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => {options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;});

using IHost host = builder.Build();
await host.RunAsync();

public class KasaJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {

        // run my task
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to pass Logger to the constructor of the KasaJob class. I've tried `builder.Services.AddTransient<KasaJob>()`, but it always blows up because Quartz can't instantiate a class with a parametrized constructor.

I've also tried calling `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` to no avail.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: `ILogger` DI works in `Quartz, 3.7.0` and `NET7`. Your version?

Comment: @scccboom Yep Quartz 3.7.0 with .NET 7.  It's a console application.

Comment: The code works. You can try to clean up the project and rebuild.

Comment: Actually, I was missing `builder.Services.AddTransient<KasaJob>();` after `.AddQuartz` call.  After that it worked.  

I previously tried to use `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` thinking that it enabled DI, but it doesn't appear to.  This [example](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/3.x/src/Quartz.Examples.AspNetCore/Startup.cs) clued me in.

Comment: `AddTransient` is not required. Job was created by `JobFactory` . `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` is the default for DI configuration.

Comment: @scccboom You are absolutely right.  Not sure why it wasn't working before.  So then calling `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` is completely unnecessary.  That confused me since it's marked as deprecated, yet the replacement method wasn't available.